# JQuery creating HTML not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create HTML using JQuery. I have a JQuery script which creates a HTML table:

```
$('<table>').attr('cellspacing', '5').addClass('blocksTable')
        .append('<tbody><tr><td>Name</td>')
        .append('<td><input type="text" value="" name="textBlockNames" class="textField"/></td></tr>')

        .append('<tr><td>Locale</td>')
        .append('<td><input type="text" value="" name="textBlockLocales" class="textField"/></td></tr>')

        .append('<tr><td>Content</td>')
        .append('<td><input type="text" value="" name="textBlockContents" class="textField"/></td></tr></tbody>')

        .append('</table>')
        .appendTo($("#idParentBlocksTable"));
```

But the table is generated like this:

```
<table class="blocksTable" cellspacing="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Locale</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <td>
        <input class="textField" type="text" name="textBlockNames" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="textField" type="text" name="textBlockLocales" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="textField" type="text" name="textBlockContents" value="">
    </td>
</table>
```

While it should be generated like this:

```
<table class="blocksTable" cellspacing="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> Name </td>
            <td>
                <input class="textField" type="text" name="textBlockNames" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Locale </td>
            <td>
                <input class="textField" type="text" name="textBlockLocales" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Content </td>
            <td>
                <input class="textField" type="text" name="textBlockContents" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I am doing wrong here? I don't know how more clearly explain the problem so I am typing anything here because the system doesn't allow me to submit the question.

Comment: You have to string all your HTML together into one value, then append it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're calling

```
.append('<tbody><tr><td>Name</td>')
```

jQuery doesn't change the HTML source of the page but adds **one (or more) DOM node(s)**. So the HTML is automatically fixed (here the row and cell are closed)

What you should do is build some HTML string and append it :

```
var html = '<tbody><tr><td>Name</td>'
html += '<td><input type="text" value="" name="tex"'...
...
html += '</tbody>';
$('<table>').attr('cellspacing', '5').addClass('blocksTable').append(html);
```

Note that appending elements to the DOM is costly. You should prefer building a large HTML string and append it once over appending many small elements.

Comment: But can you switch off this "fixing" functionality?

Comment: @xyu No, because jQuery changes the DOM, not the HTML source of the page.

Comment: @xyu internally it creates a document fragment, so it's not jquery that does the fixing, it's the browser.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a,

```
.append('<tbody><tr><td>Name</td>')
```

It gets appended to the `table`,

when you then do,

```
.append('<td><input type="text" value="" name="textBlockNames" class="textField"/></td></tr>')
```

It won't append to `td` as the context is still `table`,

What you can try to do is create all the html once and append it together.

Answer (score 0):

The first two calls `.append()` append to the *same* element (i.e. the `<table>`). One way to get round this would be to create the `<tbody>` separately and then append to that:

```
var $body = $('<tbody></tbody>').appendTo($('<table>').attr('cellspacing', '5').addClass('blocksTable'));
$body
    .append('<tr><td>Name</td>')
    .append('<td><input type="text" value="" name="textBlockNames" class="textField"/></td></tr>')

    //...etc.
```